# How to update mysql database from csv files in groovy-grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I have a table in my database which needs to updates with value for some rows and columns from csv file( this file outside of the grails application). The csv file contains large set of data with map to specific address and city. Some of the address in my application have wrong cities. So I want to get a city from database(grails application db), compare it with the city in csv file, map address to it, and add that address to the application database.

what is the best approach?

Comment: show us your code.

Comment: I want to know the theoretical approach. I am not sure how I can compare an address from grails application with the corresponding city in the csv file. Looks like you have a lots of experience. It would be helpful if you can just provide some hints.

Comment: Why not import CSV data into some buffer tables and perform all the logic within MySQL?

Comment: @Alexei Because of the security protocol I can't do that.

Comment: So you want to know how to parse the csv & check DB for each row?

Comment: Partially yes. I have 15000 addresses mapped to cities in the csv file(Correct one). In my grail-application DB I have around 700 address and some are linked to wrong cities. So I need to update my application DB with correct cities to those addresses. Note: I don't need all of those 15000 addresses or cities. Also, I am not sure which address and city have such issue, so best approach is to compare address by comparing db and csv file, and get corresponding city from csv files to update application db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Grails 3 use https://bintray.com/sachinverma/plugins/org.grails.plugins:csv to parse CSV, add the following to build.gradle. The plugin is also available for Grails 2.

```
repositories {
    https://bintray.com/sachinverma/plugins/org.grails.plugins:csv
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:csv:1+"
}
```

Then in your service use like:

```
def is 
try {   
    is = params.csvfile.getInputStream()   
    def csvMapReader = new CSVMapReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) )   
    csvMapReader.fieldKeys = ["city","address1", "address2"]
    csvMapReader.eachWithIndex { map, idx ->

        def dbEntry = DomainObject.findByAddress1AndAddress2( map.address1, map.address2 )

        if ( map.city != dbEntry.city ) {
            // assuming we're just updating the city on current entry?
            dbEntry.city = map.city
            dbEntry.save()
        }
        // do whatever logic

    }
finally {
    is?.close
}
```

This is of course a simplified version as I don't know you're csv or schema layout.

Comment: Thanks Mike W. The logic really helps. Just another quick question is that how should I approach if I don't want to use plugin or dependencies. Is there a way to connect db with out dependencies or repositories?

Comment: The plugin used above only assists with the CSV parsing, you can do this yourself but I'd recommend the plugin as it does a lot for you. Database wise, I've assumed the table you have to update has an associated Grails domain, if not you can use groovy.sql.Sql, http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html

Comment: Thanks.It already helps a lot. I am actually finishing up.My question was if I want to run the groovy script outside of the application? Just curious if it is all possible to create a groovy script that interact/connect grails application db but runs outside of the application.

Comment: Yes all doable, for the sql side of things you'd do something like https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5198873832194048 while iterating over your csv

Comment: We do need to read the csv file somewhere if we decide to go by the approach right?

Comment: With csv parsing, https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5167047587659776